# Obtaining CQI from Quectel EC25

Tags: at-command, quectel

I want to obtain the CQI parameter (channel quality indication) from my Quectel EC25. I reviewed the AT commands but I have no clue of how I could obtain this value.

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed the guide as well, and I confirm that the CQI itself is not returned by any command. Anyway, the command closer to what you are looking is probably `+CQT`.

From [EC25 AT commands guide](https://sixfab.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Quectel_EC25EC21_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.2.pdf) the command, which is a standar ETSII command so you'll find it in pretty every cellular modem, is:

> The command indicates the received signal strength `<rssi>` and the channel bit error rate `<ber>`.
> By issuing execution command

```
AT+CSQ
```

the following response is received

```
+CSQ: <rssi>,<ber> 

OK
```

in which `<rssi>` contains the received  signal  strength
indication mapped in the following way:

| `<rssi>` | Signal level |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | -113dBm or less |
| 1 | -111dBm |
| 2...30 | -109dBm... -53dBm |
| 31 | -51dBm or greater |
| 99 | Not known or not detectable |
| 100 | -116dBm or less |
| 101 | -115dBm |
| 102...190 | -114dBm...-26dBm |
| 191 | -25dBm or greater |
| 199 | Not known or not detectable |